# Configure proxy setting in a particular Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, svn, proxy

I have installed Jenkins in a Unix Machine which is behind the proxy server. I have an SVN url which is hosted in Internet. I have enabled all firewall settings and from my server end , I can able to access the SVN url by providing my proxy server details. I have created a Jenkins Job, and installed SVN plugin also. Now i need to pass proxy url to that particular job, so that Jenkins can access the SVN url and checkout the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the proxy url in a Global property in Jenkins (like PRIVATE_PROXY_URL) and, in the context of your job, copy the value of that property to the HTTP_PROXY variable or wherever you need it so the SVN plugin will be able to access it.

Another option would be to pass the URL as a Job parameter.

Regards,